# r string separation issue

Tags: r, string, split

I am dealing with few strings which are as follows

```
Col1
--------------------------
554 - partial-completion_3
4011 - structure painted
5459 - 1 int mam-corrosion issue
996 - cast iron countershock
```

My goal is to break these strings into two parts like this

```
Col1_Id   Col2_Desc
--------------------------
554       partial-completion_3
4011      structure painted
5459      1 int mam-corrosion issue
996       cast iron countershock
```

I tried using the `seperate` function

```
df_sep =   df %>% 
  separate(Col1, c("Col1_ID", "Col2_Desc"), "-")
```

This works only if there is only one **-** in a string, if there are two **-**
in a string for example

```
       `5459 - 1 int mam-corrosion issue`
```

Then the **separate** function drops the descriptions after the second **-** and the output looks like this

```
       `5459 - 1 int mam`
```

This is not what I was expecting. I was expecting an output like this below

```
    Col1_Id   Col2_Desc
    --------------------------
    554       partial-completion_3
    4011      structure painted
    5459      1 int mam-corrosion issue
    996       cast iron countershock
```

Any tips or advice is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Looks like akrun already solved this, but in the future it is better if you share your data in an easily reproducible way like `dput()` or by creating the data within code that you provide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub` to replace the first `-` with `,` and then read using `read.csv`

```
read.csv(text= sub("-", ",", df1$Col1), header=FALSE, 
          col.names=c("Col1_Id",   "Col2_Desc"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#   Col1_Id                  Col2_Desc
#1     554       partial-completion_3
#2    4011          structure painted
#3    5459  1 int mam-corrosion issue
#4     996     cast iron countershock
```

---

In the case of `separate`, there is an `extra` argument, which can be used to sort out this problem

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, Col1, into = c("Col1_Id", "Col2_Desc"), extra="merge")
#  Col1_Id                 Col2_Desc
#1     554      partial-completion_3
#2    4011         structure painted
#3    5459 1 int mam-corrosion issue
#4     996    cast iron countershock
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("554 - partial-completion_3", "4011 - structure painted", 
"5459 - 1 int mam-corrosion issue", "996 - cast iron countershock"
)), .Names = "Col1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: `extra="merge" `, nice , that worked.

Answer (score 0):

One base R alternative is `strsplit` to split the column into a list and then use `rbind.data.frame` to construct a data.frame. `SetNames` is used to conveniently set up the names in the same line.

```
setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(df1$Col1, split=" - ")),
         c("Col1_Id", "Col2_Desc"))

  Col1_Id                 Col2_Desc
1     554      partial-completion_3
2    4011         structure painted
3    5459 1 int mam-corrosion issue
4     996    cast iron countershock
```